# Toon Shader Programming/Noise Generation/Line Coloring

Tags: light, shaders, freestyle

**EDIT: A LOT OF IMPROVEMENTS**

The file: [image]

The output will look something like this (but in color):
[image: Steamboat-Willie]
(Mickey & the ship's wheel are cel objects, and the ship & grass are background objects)

***CEL SHADING***

Diffuse Frame: Instead of the "Value" node, I would like something that reads a custom property from the light(s) illuminating the object that tells it whether to illuminate the entire object (with shadows), or just illuminate the areas the rays are hitting.

specular.osl:
Can I have the specular shader only reflect lights? (like Blender Internal specular)

Displacement: 
How can I add a slight displacement to the model on any frame it moves/deforms, to give it a sort of small inconsistency, like older cartoons?

***BG SHADING***

Diffuse.osl:
When I try to change the "DiffuseSmoothness" property, nothing happens. The line always stays sharp. Also, how can I add a "NormalMap" to the shader?

Specular.osl:
I would also like the smoothness property to work & normalmap support, but I would like a specific NormalMap that always faces the direction of the specular reflection.

***FREESTYLE***

Finally, can freestyle line editor make an irregular line that looks like it was drawn with ink (cel objects) or pencil (background objects)? Not only this, but can the color of the line be based on certain material properties, such as reflection, transparency, & emission, with a color ramp defining which colors to map to the properties?

Sorry if that's a lot. I'm really new in the shading area of expertise. Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Just for clarification, do you intend to implement this as GLSL shader or is it supposed to be a node-based material for Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: @rjg It is supposed to be used as an OSL file, which will be accessed using the "Script" node.

Comment: That's not my area of expertise, but hopefully somebody in the community can help.

Comment: Hi. Could you provide the blend file using a site that does not need a registration? For instance using the classic https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon Sure thing.